# Pillow : return a NoneType when extracting EXIF ​metadata

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, exif

I tried to extract Exif metadata from a picture with Pillow.

When I import my picture on GIMP or XnView, the software returns to me Exif metadata :

[EXIF metadata on GIMP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsjSx.png)

However, when I run my Python script like this :

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

def get_exif():
  i = Image.open('./Datatest_img/DAFANCH96_023MIC07633_L.jpg')
  info = i._getexif()
  return {TAGS.get(tag): value for tag, value in info.items()}

print(get_exif())
```

the script returns to me an error as if the image did not contain EXIF ​​metadata :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_exif.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(get_exif())
  File "test_exif.py", line 15, in get_exif
    return {TAGS.get(tag): value for tag, value in info.items()}
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I also tried printing .info in my script the code return :

```
{None: (200, 200)}
```

and I running exiftool in command Line, the terminal print :

```
$ exiftool DAFANCH96_023MIC07633_L.jpg
ExifTool Version Number         : 11.99
File Name                       : DAFANCH96_023MIC07633_L.jpg
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 791 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2020:05:27 22:46:56+02:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2020:05:28 10:54:31+02:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2020:05:27 22:46:57+02:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : JPEG
File Type Extension             : jpg
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
JFIF Version                    : 1.01
Resolution Unit                 : inches
X Resolution                    : 200
Y Resolution                    : 200
Image Width                     : 4096
Image Height                    : 2944
Encoding Process                : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 1
Image Size                      : 4096x2944
Megapixels                      : 12.1
```

Anyone have an idea ? Does anyone know what's going on ? thanks.

Comment: Try printing `i.info` and also try running `exiftool` on your file to see what's really in there.

Comment: I corrected the post with the new info, excuse me my awkwardness

Comment: I *"think"* the issue is what PIL and GIMP consider EXIF information. PIL and `exiftool` seem to take the image width and resolution from the JFIF APP0 segment and don't consider them as EXIF. I think GIMP calls that *"EXIF"* I *"think"* **ImageMagick**, PIL and `exiftool` maybe only consider APP1 segment data as EXIF. I may be totally wrong and am very happy to be corrected, so if anyone knows better... ping me please. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format